# How to Prevent a user from changing lead status from "X" to "Y"

Tags: validation, validation-rule, leads

I have a marketing automation system in charge of distributing leads, and changing their respective statuses based on specific parameters. I would like to put a rule in place that would prevent it from changing the lead status from "sales qualified" back to "inbound".

Comment: Have you tried validation rule?

Comment: @SantanuBoral I tried a basic validation rule to prevent the profile from changing the status to sales qualified, but have not been able to the if-then code. Any help with that formula would be great.

Comment: Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post what you've written so far for the validation rule and where you're stuck, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful. Posting requests to write code for you generally get closed. You can edit your question using the link at the bottom left of your post at any time.

Comment: Can you try my ans below and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule will help you to throw the error `"Cannot change Lead Status from Sales Qualified to Inbound"`

```
AND(
    NOT(ISNEW()), 
    ISCHANGED(Status),
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status),"Sales Qualified"),
    ISPICKVAL(Status, "Inbound")
)
```

Note: I have not put any profile restriction in this rule. If you want that other than "System Admin" that rule will fire then change like this:

```
AND( 
    NOT(ISNEW()), 
    ISCHANGED(Status), 
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status),"Sales Qualified"), 
    ISPICKVAL(Status, "Inbound"), 
    $Profile.Name<>"System Administrator" 
)
```

For more information, refer [Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&siteLang=en_US&type=0)

Comment: this worked perfectly. Thanks for the assist, much appreciated

Comment: please accept this ans so others may find useful